# Change button id as value

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove button id and add attr as a new val() i.e any record id no

```
$("#removeid").append(btnId);
$("#removeid").val(btnId);    
$('#1', prd_row).removeAttr('id').attr('id', $("#removeid").val().trim());
```

i want an btnId val() as a button id

Comment: You don't need to use removeAttr when you are already overwriting that attribute with new value.

Comment: Changing `id` values seems like a terrible idea anyway.